# Java.lang NullPointerException in Java Applet

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, applet

Good evening all. I have been racking my brain trying to answer this question on my own but I am at a loss and considering throwing something. Let me preface my question with the fact that this was a school project that the instructor is letting me re-submit in an attempt to make a passing grade and I am not looking for a direct copy and past code but I need help to figure out how to solve this problem. The original code opens the applet and I get **Start: applet not initialized** error. In Eclipse, I get **java.lang.NullPointerException** with several lines that I have no idea where they came from. Please see code and errors list. Thanks in advance!

```
Error List
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1091)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:971)
    at SodaMachine.init(SodaMachine.java:43)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### SodaMachine

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SodaMachine extends Applet
{
    private TextField feedbackText;
    private TextField changeText;
    private TextField creditText;
    private Panel userMoneyPanel; //To hold Panel that shows current amount of money in machine, money due to user at end of transaction
    private Panel drinksPanel; //To hold Panel that shows available drink selections
    private Panel depositPanel; //To hold Panel that shows what money can be entered by user
    private Panel userFeedbackPanel;
    int colaStock = 3;
    int lemonLimeStock = 3;
    int grapeStock = 3;
    int rootBeerStock = 3;
    int waterStock = 3;
    double cost = 0.75;
    double credit = 0.00;
    double change = 0.00;


    public void init() 
    {

        //Panels to be built
        builduserMoneyPanel();
        builddrinksPanel();
        builddepositPanel();
        builduserFeedbackPanel();

        //layout manager for applet
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //add Panels to applet
        add(depositPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(userFeedbackPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(drinksPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(userMoneyPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }

    //user Money Panel build method to show money in machine and user's change
    private void builduserMoneyPanel()
    {
        Panel userMoney = new Panel();
        Label creditLabel = new Label("Credit");
        Label changeLabel = new Label("Change");
        TextField creditText = new TextField(10);
        creditText.setEditable(false);
        TextField changeText = new TextField(10);
        changeText.setEditable(false);
        userMoney.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        userMoney.add(creditLabel);
        userMoney.add(changeLabel);
        userMoney.add(creditText);
        userMoney.add(changeText);
    }

    //deposit method for user to add money to machine to make a transaction
    private void builddepositPanel()
    {
        Panel depositPanel = new Panel();
        Button nickelButton = new Button("INSERT NICKEL");
        Button dimeButton = new Button("INSERT DIME");
        Button quarterButton = new Button("INSERT QUARTER");
        Button dollarButton = new Button("INSERT DOLLAR");
        nickelButton.addActionListener(new nickelButtonListener());
        dimeButton.addActionListener(new dimeButtonListener());
        quarterButton.addActionListener(new quarterButtonListener());
        dollarButton.addActionListener(new dollarButtonListener());
        depositPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
        depositPanel.add(nickelButton);
        depositPanel.add(dimeButton);
        depositPanel.add(quarterButton);
        depositPanel.add(dollarButton);
    }

    //method to show user available drink selection to choose from
    private void builddrinksPanel()
    {
        drinksPanel = new Panel();
        Button colaButton = new Button("COLA");
        Button lemonLimeButton = new Button("LEMON LIME");
        Button grapeButton = new Button("GRAPE");
        Button rootBeerButton = new Button("ROOT BEER");
        Button waterButton = new Button("WATER");
        colaButton.addActionListener(new colaButtonListener());
        lemonLimeButton.addActionListener(new lemonLimeButtonListener());
        grapeButton.addActionListener(new grapeButtonListener());
        rootBeerButton.addActionListener(new rootBeerButtonListener());
        waterButton.addActionListener(new waterButtonListener());
        drinksPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        drinksPanel.add(colaButton);
        drinksPanel.add(lemonLimeButton);
        drinksPanel.add(grapeButton);
        drinksPanel.add(rootBeerButton);
        drinksPanel.add(waterButton);
    }

    //method to tell user if drink is out of stock or if they have not added sufficent money to purchase drink
    private void builduserFeedbackPanel()
    {
        userFeedbackPanel = new Panel();
        TextField feedbackText = new TextField();
        feedbackText.setEditable(false);

    }

    //listeners for all drink choice buttons in applet
    private class colaButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");
            if(colaStock == 0)
            {
                feedbackText.setText("Insufficent stock available. Please make another selection.");
            }

            if(credit < cost)
            {
                feedbackText.setText("Insufficent funds. Please insert more money.");
            }

            if(credit >= cost)
            {
                colaStock -= 1;
                change = credit - cost;
                if(change == 0.00)
                {
                    changeText.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    changeText.setText(dollar.format(change));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class lemonLimeButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");

            if(lemonLimeStock == 0)
            {
                feedbackText.setText("Insufficent stock available. Please make another selection.");
            }

            if(credit < cost)
            {
                feedbackText.setText("Insufficent funds. Please insert more money.");
            }

            if(credit >= cost)
            {
                lemonLimeStock -= 1;
                change = credit - cost;
                if(change == 0.00)
                {
                    changeText.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    changeText.setText(dollar.format(change));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class grapeButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");

            if(grapeStock == 0)
            {
                feedbackText.setText("Insufficent stock available. Please make another selection.");
            }

            if(credit < cost)
            {
                feedbackText.setText("Insufficent funds. Please insert more money.");
            }

            if(credit >= cost)
            {
                grapeStock -= 1;
                change = credit - cost;
                if(change == 0.00)
                {
                    changeText.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    changeText.setText(dollar.format(change));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class rootBeerButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");

            if(rootBeerStock == 0)
            {
                feedbackText.setText("Insufficent stock available. Please make another selection.");
            }

            if(credit < cost)
            {
                feedbackText.setText("Insufficent funds. Please insert more money.");
            }

            if(credit >= cost)
            {
                rootBeerStock -= 1;
                change = credit - cost;
                if(change == 0.00)
                {
                    changeText.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    changeText.setText(dollar.format(change));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class waterButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");

            if(waterStock == 0)
            {
                feedbackText.setText("Insufficent stock available. Please make another selection.");
            }

            if(credit < cost)
            {
                feedbackText.setText("Insufficent funds. Please insert more money.");
            }

            if(credit >= cost)
            {
                waterStock -= 1;
                change = credit - cost;
                if(change == 0.00)
                {
                    changeText.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    changeText.setText(dollar.format(change));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //listeners for all monetary choices available to user for purchasing drink
    private class nickelButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");
            credit += .05;
            creditText.setText(dollar.format(credit));
        }
    }

    private class dimeButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");
            credit += .10;
            creditText.setText(dollar.format(credit));
        }
    }

    private class quarterButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");
            credit += .25;
            creditText.setText(dollar.format(credit));
        }
    }

    private class dollarButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");
            credit += 1.00;
            creditText.setText(dollar.format(credit));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting fields in the builder methods. This means the fields are `null` when you add them to the container.

For example

```
  private Panel userMoneyPanel;
  ...

  private void builduserMoneyPanel()
  {
     // Panel userMoney = new Panel();  // this is wrong...
     userMoneyPanel = new Panel();
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of each of your 'build' methods you seem to be declaring your Panel variables. Most of these declarations are wrong. The variables are already declared as fields in your class and you just need to instantiate them. `drinksPanel = new Panel();` is correct; `Panel userMoney = new Panel();` is wrong. The private field `userMoneyPanel` is therefore never instantiated, causing the exception. This is a lot of code, though, so sorry if I have misidentified the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the different methods for building panels, you use **local** variables instead of initialising the fields from the class. For instance:

```
private void builduserMoneyPanel()
{
    Panel userMoney = new Panel(); // <= This is not good !
    //...
}
```

Do:

```
private void builduserMoneyPanel()
{
    userMoney = new Panel(); // initialise this.userMoney
    //...
}
```

Same for the 4 building methods.